# ASP.NET MVC - Unable to bind form values to List<Model>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have this model

```
    public class ItemClassification
    {
         public int ItemID {get; set;}
         public string ItemName {get; set;}
    }
```

and I have this form

```
   <form method="POST" action="/Home/UpdateItemClassifications">
        <table>
             <tr>
                  <th>Item ID</th>
                  <th>Item Name</th>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                  <td>
                       <input name="ItemClassification[0].ItemID" value="1"/>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                       <input name="ItemClassification[0].ItemName" value="Item One"/>
                  </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                  <td>
                       <input name="ItemClassification[1].ItemID" value="2"/>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                       <input name="ItemClassification[1].ItemName" value="Item Two"/>
                  </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                  <td>
                       <input name="ItemClassification[2].ItemID" value="3"/>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                       <input name="ItemClassification[2].ItemName" value="Item Three"/>
                  </td>
             </tr>
        </table>
   </form>
```

And I'm trying to bind these values to this controller action to loop through them and update them in the db.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateItemClassifications(List<ItemClassification> UpdatedClassifications)
    {
         //save logic here..
    }
```

For whatever reason I am not getting my posted form values bound to the ItemClassification model. Any help or direction would be appreciated. I have tried posting this form with only 1 set of values and removed the "List<>" from the controller and it mapped the values correctly.

Comment: if they are in sequence, try removing "ItemClassification" and just place [0].ItemID

Comment: If they aren't in sequence, you need to have hidden value carrying index before each item, check http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I didn't need the "ItemClassification" before the [0].ItemID, thank you for the answer [Sundeep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1606128/sundeep). I may indeed need to look at the hacked article you referenced since I may be adding a JavaScript delete function to this and it will no doubt change my indexing.